# proving an integral-defined function is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

Im studying the following exercise on generalised Riemann integrals (I'm a self-learner):

$$L(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt$$

What I managed to do :

1. Prove that L is well-defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and even.
2. Prove that $$\frac{2xt^2}{(1+x^2t^2)(1+t^2)}=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2t^2}-\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)$$

   4. using the result of question 3. (below) prove that $$\forall x \in \left]-1 ;1\right[, \  L(x)=\frac{\pi}{\ln(x+1)}$$

What I couldn't prove

3. Prove that L is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\lbrace-1;1\right\rbrace \,$ and that $$L'(x)=\frac{\pi}{1+x}$$

I have trouble finding an upper bound to prove differentiability rigourously,,  according to the differentiation theorem, it's the absolute value of the patial derivative wrt to $x$ that need be bounded

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: @Crostul and it's done ! (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L′(x) =  \frac {π}{|x|+1sgn(x)}$$

so $ L'(x)\to \pi$ if $x \to 0^+$ and $L'(x) \to-\pi $ if $ x \to 0^-$, so $L'(0)$ can't be defined.

Answer (score 2):

Given $b>0$, we have the bound
$$
\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}\leq\frac{C}{(1+t^2)^{1-\varepsilon}} ,
\qquad
|x|\leq b,
$$
for any $\varepsilon>0$, with $C$ depending on $\varepsilon$ and $b$.

Comment: I cannot see how you came up, could you elaborate ? Moreover,  according to the differentiation theorem, it's the absolute value of the patial derivative wrt to x that need be bounded

Answer (score 2):

**The final answers for $L(x)$ and $L'(x)$ mentioned in the question, are incorrect.**

Note that for a given $x$, arbitrary and small $\alpha>0$ and large enough $t$, say $t>M(x,\alpha)$ we have $$\ln(1+x^2t^2)<(x^2t^2)^\alpha$$hence $$L(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt{=\int_0^{M(x,\alpha)}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_{M(x,\alpha)}^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt\\\le\int_0^{M(x,\alpha)}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_{M(x,\alpha)}^{+\infty}\frac{(x^2t^2)^\alpha}{1+t^2}dt\\\le\int_0^{M(x,\alpha)}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(x^2t^2)^\alpha}{1+t^2}dt}$$both the latter integrals exist and are bounded, hence $L(x)$ is well-defined over $\Bbb R\quad\blacksquare$

Based on the well-definition of $L(x)$, for $x\ne -1,0,1$ we can write$$L'(x){
={d\over dx}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt\\
=\int_0^{+\infty}{d\over dx}\frac{\ln(1+x^2t^2)}{1+t^2}dt\\
=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{2xt^2}{(1+t^2)(1+x^2t^2)}dt\\
={2x\over x^2-1}\int_0^{+\infty}{1\over 1+t^2}-{1\over 1+x^2t^2}dt\\
={2x\over x^2-1}{\pi\over 2}\left[1-{1\over |x|}\right]\\
={\pi\over |x|+1}\times \text{sgn}(x)
}
$$Also simply $L'(0)=0$ and for $x=\pm 1$ we have $$L'(\pm 1){=\pm \int_0^\infty {2t^2\over (1+t^2)^2}dt\\=\pm 
\left[\tan^{-1}x-{x\over x^2+1}\right]_0^\infty
\\=\pm{\pi\over 2}
}$$finally

> $$L'(x)={\pi\over |x|+1}\text{sgn}(x)\quad,\quad x\in\Bbb R$$

Since $L(0)=0$ we obtain

> $$L(x)=\pi \ln(1+|x|)$$

Comment: Thanks ! It should be a \partial and not d in the integral for the d/dx, right ? Also when using the z Riemann integral, to put the derivative inside of the integral, one must show that abs(d/dx integrand) has an upperbound that is independent of x. Proving that L'(0)=0 is also not smth simple to me. I need help proving that I can use the Leibniz rule here

Comment: Essentially, both $\partial\over \partial x$ and $d\over dx$ denote the same operation, but $d\over dx$ is more suitable since $L(x)$ is only a function of $x$. Also to be able to substitute $d\over dx$ with $\int$, you need to show that the function is bounded and well-defined over $(x-h,x+h)$ for every $x$ and some $h>0$ so as to show it has a derivative in $x$. This one follows easily from the definition of derivative.

Comment: about the Leibniz rule (dx and int),what you say only applies to Lebesgue theory, which I have not studied yet, in the Riemann case, I need a bound as mentioned earlier, if you have a reference, I'd be grateful. How about L'(0) I can't quite get why it should be zero?